# Check file for email addresses and extract them

Tags: java, search, for-loop

Using Java, I need to figure out a way to check if a file  has any email addresses in it and then display the email addresses. Does any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

[Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) FTW

[image]

Comment: How long have you been waiting to deploy that answer? :) :) +1

Comment: It's the first XKCD I ever came across back when I was learning Perl. I've waited years for this moment!

Comment: Note that not any string with an @ in it, is a valid email address and that the correct regex to decide whether a string is a valid email address is about one a4 page of text. Other than that, still the best answer and funny :D

Answer (score 2):

The code that'll do this is outlined here:

```
Pattern pattern = 
Pattern.compile("the regex string");

Matcher matcher = 
pattern.matcher("the file");

boolean found = false;
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(match.group());
    found = true;
}
```

Loop as desired, the way I have it now is to stop when it finds the first address.

The regular expression itself can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to suffer using Java, then your lifestyle and happiness can be improved using the [Java Regex Tester](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm).